# VB.NET How to send key 46 (Chr(46)) with SendMessage

Tags: vb.net, winapi

I am Automating IBM iSeries Emulators using VB.net, created GUI that embeds the external iSeries Emulator Window in a WindowsForm Panel using the "SetParent" API .. To communicate with the iSeries Window I use the SendMessage API to send Key's to the Screen. I am aware of the sendkeys.keys in .net, but this way I dont have to SetForegroundWindow and reactivate my Form.

My program reads the output of a scale and validates if the received data is good, if so it will send the output to the iSeries Screen using this code (UserApi is my Lib):

```
For Each element As Char In CStr(txtto400.Text)
    UserApi.SendMessage(as400WindowHandle, 256, CType(Convert.ToInt32(element), IntPtr), CType(0, IntPtr))
Next
```

I done this a few times on other projects and this method works good, but in my TextBox (txtto400.Text) my weight has a Value like "000.88 KG".
SendMessage will not send the key "46" which is a period (.) Instead it would be "00088 KG"

Does anyone have an idea why this dont work? Any suggestions what I could do?

### EDIT:

### Thanks to Paul B. which gave me the hint.

Here is how I resolved it.

My SendMessage function looks like this:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)> _
Public Shared Function SendMessage( _
   ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, _
   ByVal wMsg As UInt32, _
   ByVal wParam As IntPtr, _
   ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function
```

I created a variable that holds the VK_OEM_PERIOD:

```
Public Const VK_OEM_PERIOD = &HBE
```

Created a Function that will check the Chr:

```
Public Function vk_key(key As Char) As Integer
 Select Case key
     Case Is = Chr(46)
         Return VK_OEM_PERIOD
     Case Else
        Return AscW(key)
 End Select
End Function
```

here is how I pass it to the iSeries Window:

```
For Each element As Char In txtto400.Text
   UserApi.SendMessage(as400WindowHandle, 256, vk_key(element), 0)
Next
```

Comment: We need to see the code of your SendMessage function to help on this one

Comment: WM_KEYDOWN is posted, not sent.  And uses virtual keys, not characters.  Consider sending WM_CHAR instead, message 258.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WM_KEYDOWN` message expects "The virtual-key code of the nonsystem key" as wParam (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

This happens to correspond to the key character's ASCII value for alphanumeric signs but not for all other keys. For a period I think you need to send `VK_OEM_PERIOD`.

You can find the table of virtual-key codes here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: That did it, thanks!! :-) It all makes sense now, it worked for all alphabetic and numeric keys but not for other keys.. If I check if the char is a "." and send VK_OEM_PERIOD at that point it works.. I will create a function that checks the character and then translates the value to the virtual-key code's and I should be good to go. Again thanks!