# calling winAPI functions in vb.net

Tags: c, vb.net, winapi

I have to "translate" / up-date a program that was written in C about 20 years ago to VB.net due to its old SQL connection style that isn't compatible anymore.  However, I have minimal experience with C and even less with the winAPI(which the C application uses)... I was wondering, can the same functions from the API be use in VB.net?

I have been able to add a declaration like this:

```
   <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
    Public Shared Function SetWindowText(hWnd As IntPtr, lpString As String) As Boolean
    End Function
```

to get a window Handle as IntPtr ( in vb.net). However the C program uses functions such as:

```
 BOOL NEAR GoModal( HINSTANCE hInstance, LPCSTR lpszTemplate,HWND hWnd, DLGPROC lpDlgProc, LPARAM lParam )
```

By importing the user32.dll I can't get the hWnd handle but I can get the IntPtr ( If I understood well, is a point to a window as an integer right? Kinda similar to hWnd --> I could be TOTALLY wrong, but this is what I understood)

As I go to the definition of each type (i.e: NEAR , HINSTANCE, LPCSTR, etc...) I try to find an equivalent call in VB but ... its useless. For instance, I was looking at NEAR and I guess it was to decide if two pointers were close in memory ? ( again might be wrong, it's just what I gathered).

Ultimately, my question is, would such call exist in vb.net / even be useful with the more modern framework and such?

Comment: `NEAR` was used to tell the compiler that the function `GoModal` is within the local code segment (probably 16 bit addressing) rather than in a `FAR` segment which would require a different processor instruction to call it.

Comment: So, I'm guessing that's not needed anymore with the type of memory that's used nowadays right? I mean I have used NEAR in SQL calls but never seen it in other instances

Comment: In modern Visual Studio C++ NEAR and FAR are #defined as nothing so that when they are in the code they basically are turned into nothing by the C Preprocessor. These were originally needed for 16 bit windows with the segmented address architecture of the old Intel processors (8080/86 as well as 80286/80386 which used segmented addresses that combined two 16 bit parts into a 32 bit address when running in the 8086 mode) when an address was out of the current memory segment. Would it be possible to use C++ .NET instead?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847418/how-do-i-change-the-window-title-after-starting-something-with-process-start which may be helpful and this codeproject article that uses Windows API with examples in C# and VB.NET may be helpful as well http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/825946/Csharp-VB-NET-and-WinAPI-How-to-Access-Window-of-O as well as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032523/vb-net-how-to-send-key-46-chr46-with-sendmessage

Comment: @Richard Chambers  I would gladly use C++ as it would make this a whole lot easier than VB.net. Unfortunately I am 1) an intern and therefore have no say 2) their programmers all have been coding in VB.net for min. 10 years or more and their versatility is almost all gone. I have never really done C programming but I can adapt rather quickly ( I'd hope for my sake). So anyway I try to accommodate what is given to me!  Also thanks for the explanation about the NEAR and FAR. Also if you notice my code snippet of the declaration of DllIImport in VB.NET it is exactly the same one from codeproject!

Comment: Pretty unlikely that you'll get very far without an in depth knowledge of C and Win32.

Comment: As said above, I don't really have a choice as it was given to me (never said I knew C or Win32). All I can do is try and learn as I do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break down the parameters in the function call:

```c
BOOL NEAR GoModal(HINSTANCE hInstance, 
                  LPCSTR lpszTemplate,
                  HWND hWnd, 
                  DLGPROC lpDlgProc, 
                  LPARAM lParam )
```

- `BOOL` is a 32 bit integer. You can use the `System.Boolean` type in your code, but it needs the `MarshalAsAttribute` applied to it, specifying the type as `UnmanagedType.Bool`
- `NEAR` specifies information to the compiler. When translating to .net, you can ignore it.
- `HINSTANCE` is a `Handle` to an `Instance`. Translating to .net, handles are typically defined as `IntPtr` values. This doesn't mean that it's a pointer to memory. (ie- `Marshal.Read` can't be used.)
- `LPCSTR` is a `Long` `Pointer` to a `C` style `STR`ing.  This is an `ANSI` string, so it means that the parameter needs the `MarshalAsAttribute` with `UnmanagedType.LPStr`. If this is was an out parameter, things would be more complicated, and you'd either need to pass a `StringBuilder` or use `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`/`Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem` to get unmanaged memory allocated.
- `HWND` is a `Handle` to a `Window`. Like the `HINSTANCE` it is typically marshalled as an `IntPtr`
- `DLGPROC` is a bit more complex, so I'll address it below.
- `LPARAM` is a `Long` `Parameter`. The standard implementation that Microsoft used for this type when they created the `Message` class, is `IntPtr`. You should follow suit.

As I said above `DLGPROC` is more complex. It is actually a pointer (reference) to a function. Specifically one with the signature:

```c
INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogProc(
  _In_ HWND   hwndDlg,
  _In_ UINT   uMsg,
  _In_ WPARAM wParam,
  _In_ LPARAM lParam
);
```

We've already seen `HWND` and `LPARAM`, so let's take a quick look at the other things in this signature.

- `INT_PTR` is an `Integer` `Pointer`. If that sounds familiar, it should. It's just an `IntPtr`.
- `CALLBACK` is another bit of information that the compiler uses to determine how the function should be compiled, and how people using it should send their parameters to the function. By default the .net marshal handles this, so no additional configuration is needed.
- `WPARAM` stands for `Word` `Param`. In this case, it's old terminology, and you will want to use `IntPtr` to receive the value.

To marshal a pointer to a `DLGPROC`, you will need to create a delegate with the appropriate signature:

```vb
Delegate Function DLGPROC(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, 
                          ByVal uMsg As UInt32, 
                          ByVal wParam As IntPtr, 
                          ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
```

You then need to create a function somewhere in your code, with the same signature, to receive the call from the native code. Something like:

```vb
Private Function MyDialogProc(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, 
                              ByVal uMsg As UInt32, 
                              ByVal wParam As IntPtr, 
                              ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    Return IntPtr.Zero ' Put the appropriate code here.
End Function
```

You then can add a class member to hold that delegate:

```vb
Private DialogProc As DLGPROC = New DLGPROC(AddressOf Me.MyDialogProc)
```

After all of that, you're finally ready to import the `GoModal` function prototype. (YAY!) That looks like:

```vb
<DllImport("DLL_NAME")>
Private Shared Function GoModal(ByVal hInstance As IntPtr,
                                <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> ByVal lpszTemplate As String,
                                ByVal hWnd As IntPtr,
                                ByVal lpDlgProc As IntPtr, ' More on this below
                                ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
End Function
```

We can now call the function from our code:

```vb
Dim dialogProcedure As IntPtr = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(Me.DialogProc)
Dim result As Boolean = GoModal(IntPtr.Zero, 
                                "Template", 
                                Me.Handle, 
                                dialogProcedure, 
                                New IntPtr(100))
```

Two notes about the function call:

- `IntPtr.Zero` is the same as `NULL`
- `New IntPtr(100)` creates an `IntPtr` with the specified value. (Sometimes the `LPARAM` is just a number)

And if you made it this far, Congratulations! There may be a couple bugs in the code, but this should get you going. For other Windows API types, you can find a lot of information at [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/).

If you have a lot of interop to do, it would be easier to just add a C++/CLI dll to your project and call these functions natively. It's much, much easier, and you can define the functions exactly how you want them. In addition, C++/CLI works with *any* of the .net languages.

Comment: I didn't think of writting a Dll in C and just importing it... I should've thought of it sooner because I got a good 15 functions like that. However, thank you so much for the breakdown, all of it makes much, much more sense.